# Is there an easy way to concatenate string non-literals with literals?

Tags: c

I would like to be able to do this:

```
lcd_putc("\fDeposited $" & disp_money & "\nAdd $" & temp & " more");
```

Unfortunately, the string literals and non-literals don't concatenate that easily.  I know how to concatenate two literals, and how to concatenate two non-literals (with strcat) but that's not really what I'm looking for.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf()` and `snprintf()` are good for this.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` is the way to do it.  For more advanced concatenation, consider `sprintf`:

```
sprintf (buf, "\fDeposited $%s\nAdd $%s more", disp_money, temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be searching for [sprintf](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/sprintf.html)

Example:

```
char string[50];
int file_number = 0;

sprintf( string, "file.%d", file_number );
file_number++;
output_file = fopen( string, "w" );
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that would help?

Comment: The documentation is an example.  If you are looking for built in operator support for this you are not going to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *buf = (char*)calloc(1,512);

sprintf(buf, "\fDeposited $%0.2d\nAdd $%0.2d more", disp_money, temp);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Memory management in C is manual.  To concatenate the strings, you will need to provide an array variable with enough characters to hold the final result.  You can allocate this buffer variable on the stack, as a local variable to your function, or on the heap, using malloc().

Or you can avoid allocating the buffer by avoiding performing concatenation, if what you intend to do is display the strings.  In that case, the following:

```
lcd_putc("\fDeposited $");
lcd_putc(disp_money);
lcd_putc("\nAdd $");
lcd_putc(temp);
lcd_putc(" more");
```

is a simple way to write what you could use.  This method has the disadvantage of incurring the overhead (if any) due to `lcd_putc()`.  This method has the advantage of not require concatenation of strings.

If and when you *do* need to concatenate strings, you will want to use `snprintf()` to ensure that you do not overflow your buffer (see the name of this web site), so do not use `sprintf()`.

Just to show you the way for that future day when you need to concatenate strings:


 `#define STR_DEPOSITED "\fDeposited $"

 #define STR_ADD "\nAdd $"

 #define STR_MORE " more"

int total_length = strlen(STR_DEPOSITED) + strlen(STR_ADD) + strlen(STR_MORE) + strlen(disp_money) + strlen(temp) + 1;

char * buffer = malloc(total_length + sizeof(char));

snprintf(buffer, "%s%s%s%s%s", STR_DEPOSITED, disp_money, STR_ADD, temp, STR_MORE);`

You can also accomplish the same thing using `strncpy(), strncat()`.  As a side note, also consider using `strnlen()` on the variables, in order not to read beyond the end of non-terminated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not first class objects in C, so there is no language support for concatenation in the way you describe. There are, however, a lot of different functions that you can call that give you the output you need.

Probably the easiest to work with is `sprintf`.  Be aware that you must supply an output buffer large enough to hold the resultant string, and sprintf doesn't do any bounds checking, if you have access to `snprintf` or `sprintf_s` then use that instead.

```
char output[SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_VALUE];
sprintf (output, "\fDeposited $%s\nAdd $%s more", disp_money, temp);
```

`%s` in the sprintf string represents a place where a string parameter will be inserted, the first % is the first argument (disp_money) and the second % is the second argument (temp).